# android camera hardware control failure

Tags: android, camera

Hi I am trying to work on a hardware camera control in android, 
I am able to get the preview of the camera on the surface view, 
however I am unable to record any video, as on starting the video recording I get the following error:

Media server died

Camera server died

ICamera died

error 100

the code for capture is  as under

```
    public void onCaptureClick(View view){
        if(!isRecording)
            new MediaPrepareTask().execute(null,null,null);
        else{
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            mCamera.lock();
            setCaptureButtonText("Start");
            isRecording = false ;
            releaseCamera();
        }

    }
```

This is the media prepare task

```
class MediaPrepareTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
         if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
             // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
             // now you can start recording
             mMediaRecorder.start();
             Log.i(TAG,"Media recording started");
             isRecording = true;
         } else {
             // prepare didn't work, release the camera
             releaseMediaRecorder();
             return false;
         }
         return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
        if(!result){
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
        setCaptureButtonText("Stop");
    }

}
```

This is where I set the property for recording

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){
        Log.i(TAG,"Starting to prepare");
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters() ;
        Log.i(TAG,"Got Property");
        List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSize = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size optimalSize = CameraHelper.getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSize,
                mPreview.getWidth(), mPreview.getHeight());
        CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
        profile.videoFrameWidth = optimalSize.width ;
        profile.videoFrameHeight = optimalSize.height ;

        parameters.setPreviewSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        Log.i(TAG,"Set Parameters");
        try{
//      //  mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mPreview.getSurfaceTexture());

        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder());
        }catch(IOException iOEx){
            iOEx.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to set preview display ");
            return false ;
        }
        ////////////////////////////////now for the media recorder ///////////////////////
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        Log.i(TAG,"Set camera for recorder");
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);
        Log.i(TAG,CameraHelper.getOutputMediaFile(CameraHelper.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());
         mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(CameraHelper.getOutputMediaFile(
                    CameraHelper.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());
            // END_INCLUDE (configure_media_recorder)

            // Step 5: Prepare configured MediaRecorder

            Log.i(TAG,"Set the ouptut format");
            try {

                mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                return false;
            }
            Log.i(TAG,"All is well");
            return true;

    }
```

Comment: why are u using an ascync task to start your recording

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is for anyone reading the question

the issue is with the surface to be added to the media recorder as well,

just add the surface to the media recorder and it works